# Laravel 5 NeoEloquent findByProperty

Tags: laravel, neo4j, laravel-5, neoeloquent

Im integratting Neo4j and Laravel 5 with NeoEloquent. I cant get a node by a property, only by node id like the example:

`User::find(1);`

What I want:

```
User::findByName('Some Name');
```

Comment: `User::whereName('Some Name')->first()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to get Eloquent to do this is:

```
User::whereName('Some Name')->first()
```

You could add a static `findByName` function to your User model to do this as `User::findByName` if you like.